# Result is returned from MySQL but not from Oracle

Tags: java, mysql, oracle

When I connect to an Oracle database the code below is not fetching the data. I have tried in MySQL and it is working properly with results returned, but in Oracle it's going to the `else` section.

```java
if (e.getSource() == b1) {

    String text1 = t1.getText();

    String text2 = t2.getText();
    try {

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "pratik");

//                           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
//                           Connection
        //con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/pratik", "root", "system");

        String sql = "select id,password from admin where id=? and password=?";

        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        pstmt.setString(1, text1);

        pstmt.setString(2, text2);

        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        int i = 0;

        if (rs.next()) {
            //dispose();
            System.out.println("Success");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Successfull", "Sucess", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            i++;
            adminsuccess as = new adminsuccess();
            as.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Failed", "Failed", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are able to connect to Oracle and can you also paste your pl/sql code here.

Comment: Your creating connection to Oracle and immediately you are connecting to MySQL which one do you want?

Comment: Please describe the goal you want to achieve in the question so, anyone sees this post instantly understand the meaning of the question. However, it's a good question.

Comment: i want to perform the login module with the help of pl/sql database using java swing

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used a connection string a little bit different from the one you have.  I've used:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe
```